# Unable to configure Gunicorn to serve a flask app running another loop concurrently

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I have a simple flask app, say like this:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

I also have a slack bot reading messages

```
#bot.py
def serve(self):
    while True:
            message, channel = self.parse_slack_output(self.slack_client.rtm_read())
            if message and channel:
                self.handle_message(message, channel)
            time.sleep(self.READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY)
```

I want both the codes to run concurrently. So in `app.py` I do:

```
#app.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import threading
    import bot

    flask_process = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
    bot_process = threading.Thread(target=bot.serve)
    bot_thread.start()
    flask_thread.start()
```

This code works as expected with `$ python app.py`, But when I bring in `gunicorn` the bot thread doesn't seem to work.

I have tried:

```
gunicorn app:app
gunicorn --workers=2 app:app
gunicorn --threads=2 app:app
```

I also tried the `multiprocessing` library and got the same results.

Any idea how this issue can be tackled? Thanks.

**Edit**: I now understand how lame this question is. I shouldn't be writing code in `if __name__ = "__main__":` block. That is not what is run by `gunicorn`. It directly picks up the app and runs it. Still have to figure how to make it handle the bot thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have made this work with the following solution:

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
import threading
import bot

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    bot_process = threading.Thread(target=bot.serve)
    return app

app = create_app()

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

This makes sure that `gunicorn --workers=1 app:app` runs both the app and the bot in different threads. While this works, one drawback with this solution is I am not able to scale up the number of workers to > 1. As this would not only scale the app thread, but also the bot thread, which I don't want. The bot would then unnecessarily listen for messages in two threads.

Any better solution in your mind? please convey it. Thanks.